# unaligned memory access difference on Solaris and Linux

Tags: c, linux, solaris, memory-alignment

I wrote a program on linux(x86,32-bit),everything works fine.But when I try to compile and run the same source code on Solaris (SPARC,64-bit),I got a bus error(SIGBUS).The message from gdb is as follows:

```
gdb) where
#0  0xff2aa57c in number () from /lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xff2a9a70 in __doscan_u () from /lib/libc.so.1
#2  0xff2b0014 in vsscanf () from /lib/libc.so.1
#3  0xff2aeb90 in fscanf () from /lib/libc.so.1
#4  0x00010940 in main (argc=4, argv=0xffbff48c) at wHeap.c:22
```

It turns out the bug is occurred because of the fscanf function, and the corresponding code snip is as follows:

```
while( fscanf(input,"%[^,],%hu,%u,%u,%[^\n]\n",record.name,&record.race,&record.class,&record.id,record.guild) != EOF){
......
}
```

basically, I try to extract the information from a comma-separated-value file and store them in an array of structs(record),which for example like:

```
Rod'rod,1,4,103026,Project Peace
Ceru,1,6,89351,World Keepers
Belget,2,9,246708,Radiant Heaters
```

The record struct is as follows:

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct {                                                          
     char name[MAXNAME];                                                       
     unsigned short race;                                                  
     unsigned int class;                                                   
     unsigned int id;                                                      
     char guild[MAXGUILD];                                                       
}record;
```

As you may notice, I used the pragma pack to try to prevent the alignment difference between these two machines.

Comment: Show us the definition of your struct (`record`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot take the address of a non-`char` element of a packed structure and access the element through that pointer. In general, you should **never use packed structures**. They are a serious code smell and indicate that you're probably doing something horribly wrong. If you insist on keeping the packed structure despite all pleas of sanity, you can use intermediate variables and pass their addresses to `scanf`, then assign into the `struct`.

Comment: Yeah,the thing is I really need the packing,and your solution actually works,thx a lot.

Comment: @flyingV: Are you sure that you need the packing here? If you were sending bytes to a piece of hardware then I could see it but not for something like this unless you're being lazy and using `fwrite` and `fread` to persist and load these structures; if the latter then you have byte order issues that a packed structure won't take care of so you should do it all by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Is the Solaris machine running on hardware that has harder alignment requirements than, say, x86?

Your comment in pmg's answer implies that you've turned off the padding, which would trigger exactly that kind of error on e.g. [SPARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC).

Answer (score 0):

How is your struct defined?

Like this?

```
struct X {
  char name[MAXNAME],
  short race,
  unsigned class,
  unsigned id,
  char guild[MAXGUILD],
  /* possibly more members ... */
};
```

If it's different, the `scanf` conversion specification does not match the arguments.

Comment: Really? Shouldn't the strings be actual char arrays?

Comment: @pmg The name and guild are fixed sized char arrays,and the struct is using #pragma pack(1) to prevent the alignment

Comment: Ah! `#pragma` ... try without it (it may be aligning the short to some alignment Solaris doesn't like)

Comment: The use of non-recognized `#pragma` invokes unspecified behaviour. In the case of `#pragma pack`, *apparently on linux "it works" and on Solaris it doesn't*.

Comment: **DO NOT USE `#pragma pack` OR ANYTHING LIKE IT**.

Comment: @pmg actually GCC probably ignores it, in other words the code works on Linux, but not on Solaris because the #pragma does not work on Linux, but it does on Solaris.

Comment: @Spudd86: probably Linux/SPARC emulates unaligned loads/stores, it does for MIPS and ARM (depending on some sysctl) IIRC.

Comment: @Spudd86: `arch/sparc/kernel/unaligned.c`, `arch/sparc/kernel/una_asm.S` looks like it.

Comment: @R.. so is there any other way to do it if I really need to keep the struct packed?

Answer (score 0):

`SIGBUS` usually indicates an alignment exception or an attempt to access memory that physically doesn't exist (maybe some inexistent address in some device's MMIO space).

Linux in many architectures emulates unaligned loads/stores, for SPARC look at `arch/sparc/kernel/unaligned.c` and `arch/sparc/kernel/una_asm.S`. Linux/ARM has a sysctl which lets you select whether to crash / log and emulate / emulate silently on unaligned memory access. Apparently, Linux/SPARC doesn't have the equivalent sysctl.